# mysqldbcompare giving Compare table checksum FAIL error

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

Running `mysqldbcompare` on two test databases on same server. There is no data discrepancy in any table but showing following message which I'm not able to understand. Any help is appreciated.

```
TABLE         a                                     pass    pass    -       
            - Compare table checksum                                FAIL    
            - Find row differences                                  pass     

TABLE         b                                      pass    pass    -       
            - Compare table checksum                                FAIL    
            - Find row differences                                  pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the simple approach (table checksum) failed, but that the rows are identical, which is a pass.  Since the row checksum takes a lot longer than the table checksum, you want to have table checksums pass as much as possible to avoid subsequent row checksums.